# How do you ignore error messages from an $http GET request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I have a function that is supposed to see if my database has a particular link or not. I am unsure whether it is not possible to do this, or if I am just doing it wrong. I am using an Angular HTTP GET request, and if the object is found, I try to return it. Here is what I have:

```
var foo = function(list, value) {
  for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    $http.get(list[i]).then(function(object) {
        var dbObject = object.data;
        if(contains(dbObject, value) {
            return list[i];
          }
        });
    }
  }
};
```

So, I am hoping to return valid URLs that link to a JSON object that contains that value. Is there a better way to do this? Right now, it throws a Not Found Error before the process even finishes, and I am hoping to find a way to ignore the error from stopping my program.

Comment: You should read up on promises. The function `foo` will not return anything. It just starts the request, whose response is passed to your callback but not used further.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is some flaw in the logic here, and $http.get() returns a promise. It will not get resolved if you get http error. In order to tap into the error handling, you actually have to pass an error handling function that will  be called on promise rejection.

```
 $http.get(list[i]).then( success_handler, error_handler );
```

Also, as it was mentioned in comments by Thomas , you probably are not using it correctly. Your method will start all the get requests and return. The results of these get requests will come later and on each result the success or error handler will get executed.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of promises then use the `$q.all` method to return and test all results.

```js
(function (ng) {
  'use strict';
  
  ng.module('HttpDemo')
    .factory('LinkChecker', LinkChecker)
    .controller('LinkCheckerDemoController', LinkCheckerDemoController);
  
  function LinkChecker ($q, $http) {
    function LinkCheckerFunc (links, value) {
      return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
        var linkPromises = [];
      
        ng.forEach(links, function (link) {
          linkPromises.push($http.get(link));
        });
        
        $q.all(linkPromises)
          .then(_onGetLinksSuccess, reject);

        function _onGetLinksSuccess (responses) {
          var validLinks = [];

          ng.forEach(responses, function (linkToCheck) {
            var link = linkToCheck.data;

            if (contains(link, value) {
              validLinks.push(link);
            }
          });

          resolve(validLinks);
        }
      });
    }
    
    return (LinkCheckerFunc);
  }

  function LinkCheckerDemoController (LinkChecker, $log) {
    var linkCheckerDemoVM = this;

    linkCheckerDemoVM.checkLinks = checkLinks;

    // example usage
    function checkLinks () {
      var validLinks = new LinkChecker(
        linkCheckerDemoVM.links,
        linkCheckerDemoVM.value
      );

      validLinks.then(_onGetValidLinksSuccess, _onGetValidLinksError);

      function _onGetValidLinksSuccess (links) {
        $log.info('Valid Links', link);
      }

      function _onGetValidLinksError (err) {
        $log.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
})(angular);
```